# Long running query on AWS Aurora MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-aurora

I have a table with approximetly 70 milion rows on AWS Aurora MySQL serverless. When I run below query it tooks more than 20 minutes to finish:

```
SELECT location_id AS LocationID
, location_date_key AS BusinessDayKey
, HOUR(location_datetime_start) AS Hour
, CEILING(AVG(VALUE)) AS Value
FROM queue_length
WHERE location_id IN @locationIDs
AND location_date_key BETWEEN 20210914 AND 20210921
GROUP BY location_id
, location_date_key
, HOUR(location_datetime_start);
```

I have appropriate covering index but it still run for so long. When drop the Hour function from the GROUP BY clause it runs within few seconds. I have tried to add generated column but it didn't help. Please find below EXPLAIN output for the query:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfpCL.png)

Do you have any ideas how to make it faster ?

Comment: It's been some time since this question was asked. What was your resolution? If still unresolved, please post the create table statement.